# opends:Is there a way for root user account/root Dns to send account notifications based on the password policies?

Tags: ldap, opendj, opends

Description :
 Enabled SMTP handler and mail properties global configuration via dsconfig, enabled SMTP handler in root user password policy, also configured root user password policy for password expiration notification, created a new root user, assigned root user password policy to that root user. 
 Any password change (reset) or password expiry warning for this root user is not notified to the email id configured in the recipient address of the SMTP Handler. This works fine for 'Default Password Policy' and for any password related changes to the end user (users under ou=user node). But notification does not work for root DNs/root users and it's password policies.

Is there a way to send email notifications or alerts for any root user based on it's password policy. Kindly let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The root user effectively doesn't have a password policy. You should not just the root user for anything. That's for the server itself. You should create another admin user with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Actually, in OpenDJ it has... There is a Root DN Password Policy. I don't know why notification doesn't work. It should. I will try to reproduce.